# Problems running appium tests for an android device using python

Tags: android, python, selenium, appium

I am trying to run a test written in python that uses appium to browse to a given URL using the chrome app installed on a physical android device.

I am using Pycharm as my IDE on a Mac.

The problem i am getting seems easy to fix, i thought i had fixed it but it is still cropping up.

The error when i try to run my script is:

```
WebDriverException: Message: u'A new session could not be created. (Original error: Could not find adb. Please set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable with the Android SDK root directory path.)'
```

The path to my SDK is:

```
/Volumes/ADATA HD710/Android emulator
```

The `adb` is in `/Volumes/ADATA HD710/Android emulator/platform-tools`

I have set the path both on my mac and in the environment variables section in Pycharm but i still am getting this error when i run the script.

Is there anything obvious i have missed?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I should add that i have run appium-doctor.js and this reported no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Path as:
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/Macbook-Name/Android/sdk/tools
and 
export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/Macbook-Name/Android/sdk/platform-tools
The path should point to both the platform-tools folder and the tools folder.